# Using Filter and ValidatorAttribute causes System.ArgumentNullException in ctor of ValidationContext

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-web-api

I got an asp webapi project and I want to use a custom validatorattribute to do some special validation in my api. For that purpose I added a filter into my api (nothing special currently):

```
public class LogFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public LogFilter()
    {

    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext ActionContext)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Action Method {0} executing at {1}", ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()), "Web API Logs");

        if (ActionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false)
        {
            ActionContext.Response = ActionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ActionContext.ModelState);
        }
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Action Method {0} executed at {1}", actionExecutedContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName, DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()), "Web API Logs");
    }
}
```

Next step I did is to create a new ValidatorAttribute called GroupValidatorAttribute (There is currently NO special implementation, it is just a minimal working example for demonstrating my problem):

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class GroupValidatorAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("" + validationContext.DisplayName + " cant be null");
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

So and finaly, we need a model-class using the GroupValidator attribute:

```
[GroupValidator]
public class Student
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

For sure there is also a controller, which has an endpoint with type post, which should get an object of class student (my model) from the body:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Body")]
    public HttpResponseMessage BodyTest(int id, [FromBody] Student student)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,
            "Suc");
    }
```

Okay, so far so good. It nearly works as expected, but one case is driving me into madness. If I send (post) an empty body to my endpoint in the api, there occures an System.ArgumentNullException.

This is the full exception:

"ExceptionMessage": "Der Wert darf nicht NULL sein.\r\nParametername: instance",
    "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentNullException",
    "StackTrace": "   bei System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationContext..ctor(Object instance, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, IDictionary`2 items)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Validation.Validators.DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate(ModelMetadata metadata, Object container)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ShallowValidate(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.ValidateNodeAndChildren(ModelMetadata metadata, BodyModelValidatorContext validationContext, Object container, IEnumerable`1 validators)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Validation.DefaultBodyModelValidator.Validate(Object model, Type type, ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, String keyPrefix)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.d__18.MoveNext()\r\n--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- Ende der Stapelüberwachung vom vorhergehenden Ort, an dem die Ausnahme ausgelöst wurde ---\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   bei System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__15.MoveNext()"

In my debugger I can see that the methods in my filter and the methods in my validator are NOT hit. Is anybody who can help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `ArgumentNullException("instance")` exception is generated from constructor of `ValidationContext`because `instance` is null in your case.

The code-snippet of constructor of `ValidationContext`: [Source code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationContext.cs#L99)

```
public ValidationContext(object instance, IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
                         IDictionary<object, object> items) 
{
    if (instance == null) {
       throw new ArgumentNullException("instance");
    }
    ....
```

> Now, to your question : In my debugger I can see that the methods in
>   my filter and the methods in my validator are NOT hit.

The call stack is something like

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidator.Validate() ->
            DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute.GetValidationResult() ->
            GroupValidatorAttribute.IsValid()
```

The constructor of `ValidationContext` is created at `Validate()` stage (where `null` exception is raised) but your implementation of `IsValid()` is called later only after `null` checking is already performed. Hence, `IsValid()` is never hit your case.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Is there any advise you could give me to solve that problem, without stopping to use the custom validator attribute?

Comment: @chris000r Depends, what you want to do. But don't think your `GroupValidator` is placed for a purpose at `Class` level.

Comment: For demonstration purpose I shrinked the code a little bit. The GroupValidator has a constructor, where you can specifiy the names of the properties the validator should have a look at it. On Validation the GroupValidator shall look, if one of the Properties of the list (from the constructor) is set (not null and a value). So It works very will, but not if the body is empty. There I get the exception listed in the beginning.

Comment: @chris000r Sounds like you need `[Required]` attribute on few properties. Another option you have is to include `ExceptionFilterAttribute` that will handle cases where parameter is null.

Comment: Required is not what I need I think. In case of the student-class (for example) I want at least one attribute not to be null.